# Can i create a materialized view on two different database having their own tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

Can i create a materialized view on two different database having their own tables?

Let's say I have two databases, A & B. A has a table called emp and B has a table called cust. I want to create a materialized view on emp & cust).

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you should. How large are the tables, how good is the connection between them? How often are they refreshed? You could make two materialized views and then make a third based on joining the two. This way if the refresh of the base table fails you still have your joined table.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you can't do this... it should be easy enough to test, but the refresh may have to be a complete refresh (fast may not be possible in this type of scenario).  My recommendation (similar to kevinsky's comment) would be to create 2 mviews as fast refreshes over their respective db links, then create a regular view that joins the 2 mviews.... instead of creating a third mview that refreshes from the other 2 mviews.